# Ant property value as parameter variable In JENKINS

Tags: jenkins, ant, jenkins-workflow

I am working on Jenkins. 
I have built a job1 with secret text: username and Password variable as

```
  APP1_Dev_password
```

And using this variable from my ANT script by sending this variable in the predefined parameter to my other job2. I am accessing this variable using

```
<property name="DBPassword" value="${APP1_Dev_password}"/>
```

This works well. 
But my ant script is a single generalized script for all my applications. 
So I have get this APP1_Dev_password string constructed automatically from my ant script using

```
<property name="constructPasswordVariable" value="${APPLICATIONNAME}_${ENVIRON}_password"/>
<echo message= "constructPasswordVariable: ${constructPasswordVariable}" />
```

This clearly prints me constructPasswordVariable as APP1_Dev_password.
Now i have to use this value of the constructPasswordVariable property as a variable to fetch from the job1.

```
<echo message= "PasswordValue: ${${constructPasswordVariable}}" />
```

This statement fails. Can you guide me of how to work on this.

SOLUTION

```
<property name="constructPasswordVariable" value="${env.Module}_${env.Environment}_password"/>
<echo message= "constructPasswordVariable: ${constructPasswordVariable}" />
<propertycopy name="prop" from="${constructPasswordVariable}"/>
<echo message= "ENV VALUE: ${prop}" />
```

Output

```
constructPasswordVariable: APP1_Dev_password
ENV VALUE: asdhasd
```

Comment: `${APPLICATIONNAME}_${ENVIRON}_password` can be used directly? I missed something?

Comment: @Rao - ${APPLICATIONNAME}_${ENVIRON}_password gives the value as APP1_Dev_Password. But i have to use this value as a variable ${APP1_Dev_Password} to fetch the secret text saved in my Build bindings. My jenkins job has a secret text with password variable in the name of APP1_Dev_Password. So to fetch this value i have to use the value received from ${APPLICATIONNAME}_${ENVIRON}_password. Dont know how to do this???

Answer (score 0):

Ant says nested property is not directly supported. Referring documentation from [here](http://ant.apache.org/faq#propertyvalue-as-name-for-property)

However, it can be achieved using library [Flaka](http://code.google.com/p/flaka/)

**Sample:** from above reference

```
<project xmlns:fl="antlib:it.haefelinger.flaka">
  <fl:install-property-handler/>
  <property name="foo" value="foo.value"/>
  <property name="var" value="foo" />
  <property name="buildtype" value="test"/>
  <property name="appserv_test" value="//testserver"/>
  <echo>
    #{${var}} = foo.value
    <!-- nested property -->
    #{appserv_${buildtype}}
  </echo>
</project>
```

There is another reference [here](http://marc.info/?l=ant-user&m=108587389105636) which make it possible without additional library as well.

**Sample:**

```
<project default="test">

<property name="foo" value="ABC"/>
<property name="pfoo" value="foo"/>

<target name="test">
  <echo file="deref.properties">
deref: $${${pfoo}}
  </echo>

  <property file="deref.properties"/>
</target>
```

Comment: I receive java.io.FileNotFoundException: /jenkins/JOB1/deref.properties (Permission denied) when i execute the 2nd sample without library.

Comment: @Jasmine, I could not try first sample with library. However, tried the 2nd sample as it is without any change and it indeed worked. Hope you might have tried the sample as it is before implementing in your project, right?

Comment: propertycopy helps me in this. So now i can dynamically use the constructPasswordVariable from ANT for all the app passwords stored in Jenkins job